# Is there a Lifecycle hook in angular 8 that is called when an elements button is clicked

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I have a main component that contains two nested components, one of the components contains input fields(2) and a button to add an item, the other sibling component displays the items in a loop.

I have a service that picks the values from the inputting component and updates its array in the service itself.

Whenever I fill the inputs and submit the service adds the new item to the array, but i need to update the sibling component that needs this list to display.

I know I have to obtain the values from the service since it has an updated array.

I dont know which lifecylce hook that I can use in the listing sibling component to fetch the new list since it seems ngOnInit is not called on clicking the Add button.

I dont want to use an event emitter.

**Parent Component**

```
export class ShoppingComponent implements OnInit {
  ingredients:Ingredient[];

  constructor(private shoppingListService: ShoppingListService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ingredients = this.shoppingListService.getIngredients();
  }

}
```

**parent html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <app-shoppinglistedit></app-shoppinglistedit>
        <hr>
        <app-shoppinglist></app-shoppinglist>
    </div>
</div>
```

The two child components put in the parent component:

***Listing sibling***

```
export class ShoppinglistComponent implements OnInit {
  ingredients: Ingredient[];

  constructor(private shoppingListService: ShoppingListService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ingredients = this.shoppingListService.getIngredients();
    this.oldLength = this.ingredients.length;
  }

}
```

***it's html/template***

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let ingridient of ingredients" >
        {{ ingridient.name }} <span class="badge badge-success badge-pill ml-auto">{{ ingridient.amount }}</span>
    </a>
</ul>
```

***The Adding Sibling***

```
export class ShoppinglisteditComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('nameRef', {static: true}) itemName:ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('amountRef', {static: true}) itemAmount:ElementRef;

  constructor(private shoppingListService: ShoppingListService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onAddNewItem(){
    const name = this.itemName.nativeElement.value;
    const amount = +this.itemAmount.nativeElement.value;
    const ingredient = new Ingredient(name, amount);

    this.shoppingListService.addIngredient(ingredient);
    console.log("All ingredients: ");
    console.log(this.shoppingListService.getIngredients());

  }
}
```

***it's template - html***

```
<div class="row col-sm-12">
    <form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" #nameRef>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                <input id="amount" class="form-control" type="number" name="amount" #amountRef>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button class="btn btn-success mr-2" type="button" (click)="onAddNewItem()">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>&nbsp;Add Item
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger mx-2" type="button">
                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt" (click)="onDeleteIngredient()"></i>&nbsp;Delete Item
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary mx-2" type="button">
                    <i class="fas fa-adjust" (click)="onClearItem()"></i>&nbsp;Clear Item
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't using EventEmitter will be tricky, CPU resources consumming and non-reactive. Let me propose you something :

First create an `@Input() ingredients: Ingredient[]` to your component **ShoppinglistComponent**. You already get ingredients in your parent component, so you can pass them to any child component (ShoppinglistComponent in our case)
Then add an `@Output() ingredientAdded = new EventEmitter()` to your component **ShoppinglisteditComponent** that you you will fire inside your *onAddNewItem* method.
In your **ShoppinglistComponent** listen to the output `(ingredientAdded)="insertNewIngredient($event)"`

```
insertNewIngredient(addedIngredient: Ingredient): void {
  this.ingredients = this.ingredients.concat(addedIngredient)
}
```

As you pass your ingredients to your **ShoppinglistComponent** with the input, it will automatically update your view. No need for Lifecycle hooks, just use some fair reactive code.

**P-S:**

You really should use Reactive forms or Template-Driven forms in your **ShoppinglisteditComponent** as you want to manage a form and Angular do it very very well (don't reinvente the wheel). Here is some code using Reactive forms (don't forget to include **FormsModule** and **ReactiveFormsModule**

```
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    fb: FormBuilder,
    private shoppingListService: ShoppingListService
  ) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      name: ['', Validator.required],
      amount: [0, [Validator.required, Validator.min(0)]]
    })
  }

  onAddNewItem(){
    const { name, amount } = this.form.value;
    const ingredient = new Ingredient(name, amount);
    this.shoppingListService.addIngredient(ingredient);
    console.log("All ingredients: ");
    console.log(this.shoppingListService.getIngredients());
  }
```

```html
<div class="row col-sm-12">
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onAddNewItem()">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input formControlName="name" id="name" class="form-control" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                <input formControlName="amount" id="amount" class="form-control" type="number" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button class="btn btn-success mr-2">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>&nbsp;Add Item
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger mx-2" type="button">
                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt" (click)="onDeleteIngredient()"></i>&nbsp;Delete Item
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary mx-2" type="button">
                    <i class="fas fa-adjust" (click)="onClearItem()"></i>&nbsp;Clear Item
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```